# Finding the largest Number

Tags: java, for-loop

In the code shown below, I am hardcoding to return the highest int value that was found in for loop.

In the for loop, it is returning each number of letters from " myName is popy" as

- 6
- 2
- 3

It should print out "MyName" as it has the most character in each word that was found. The problem i faced , i am hardcoding it to maxNo == 6. Should i use a nested forloop or there is a simplified way ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String[] name = "myName is popy".split(" ");
    int maxNo = 0;
    int storeLargestNo = 0;
    String longestWord = "";

    for(int i = 0; i  < name.length; i++){
        maxNo = name[i].length();
        System.out.println("Number of each " +  maxNo);

    //-- **HardCoded** --
        if(maxNo== 6){
            longestWord = name[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("longest Name found is " + longestWord);

}
```

----------------------**Solved**---------------------- 
i have come out with a solution , I use ArrayList instead and used Collections.max() . By doing so , its cleaner.

```
public String longestWord() {

    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Write in a sentence : ");
    String[] userInput = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> wordsArr2 = new ArrayList<String>();


    String longestWord = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length;i++){
        wordsArr2.add(userInput[i]);
    }

    longestWord = Collections.max(wordsArr2);
    return longestWord;
}
```

Comment: Why have you hardcoded maxNo to 6? You could just keep it as 0.

Answer (score 2):

Corrected code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] name = "myName is popy".split(" ");
    int maxNo = 0;
    int storeLargestNo = 0;
    String longestWord = "";

    for(int i = 0; i  < name.length; i++){
        int temp = name[i].length(); 
        System.out.println("Number of each " +  temp);

        if(maxNo < temp){
            maxNo = temp;
            longestWord = name[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("longest Name found is " + longestWord);

}
```

Don't use any nested Loop you can use a temporary variable if you want to store value and compare it with the previous length of the word and if it is greater then change the value `maxNo` and change the `longestWord` value.

Comment: Please provide some relevant explanation alongside, rather than just letting the OP copy-paste the answer.

Comment: if maxNo = 0 . why should we use if(maxNo < 0) ?

Comment: I didn't get what you want to say, In temp, I am calculating the value of each word if it is Greater than the before the max length of a word I will change the value of max length and also the longest string value.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than tracking the length of the highest word why not keep the longest String?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] name = "myName is popy".split(" ");
    String longestWord = "";

    for(int i = 0; i  < name.length; i++){
        System.out.println("and its length is " + longestWord.length());

        if(name[i].length() > longestWord.length()){
            longestWord = name[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("longest Name found is " + longestWord);
}
```

The change to the if statement here ensures the longest word will be updated rather than tracking the actual length as each word size will be unknown.

Only issue with this is there is no handling for two words of equal length.

Comment: `System.out.println("and its length is " + longestWord.length());`

Answer (score 0):

To get the result without hard coding, you can follow the following algorithm:

1. Initialize `maxNo = 0` and `longestWord = ""`
2. For every String `current` in array `name[]`, do the following
   a. `currentLength = current.length()`
   b. If `currentLength > maxNo`, set `maxNo = currentLength` and `longestWord = current`

This way, you can avoid hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like,

No need to store the length of longest name in variable, you can directly compare current word's length with previous word.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] name = "myName is popy".split(" ");
        String longestWord = "";

        for(int i = 0; i  < name.length; i++){
            if(longestWord.length() < name[i].length()){

                longestWord = name[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("longest Name is :" + longestWord);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] name = "myName is popy".split(" ");
    int strlen = 0;
    String longestName = null;
    for(String rec: name)
    {
        rec.length();
        if(rec.length() > strlen)
        {
            strlen = rec.length();
            longestName = rec.toString();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Longest Name is : "+longestName);
}
```